# 7-month old labrador has a leg injury

Tags: dogs, injury

I have a 8-month old lab that injured his front leg after hopping down from the back of a truck before I could let him down. Since then, he has had an off-and-on limp, and I have stopped all exercise. He is now almost at the 6 week mark of being injured and still no improvements.

I had the vet check him out, and ended up doing xrays on his elbow with no luck. We put him on anti-inflammatories for 10 days at about 3weeks into the injury, and that seemed to help him a lot for normal roaming in the house and going outside to the restroom, but only to an extent. He has been off of the anti-inflammatories for 4 days now and the limp is just as bad as it was before i put him on them. will be picking up another prescription of them today to help ease the pain.

So I have been closely watching on my dogs movements and actions and have seemed to see that since the injury when laying down he always folds his paw on the injured leg so that it is facing upwards.

It seems to me like it relieves the pain somehow and I'm thinking that this could be a sign that he has some sort of ligament damage to his carpal ligaments or maybe a chipped bone. Also, the way he limps to keep his weight off his leg is when his wrist is almost fully extended when it has the most pressure on that joint area. I checked the range of motion which seems normal but when extending the wrist forward you can tell he doesnt like it.

An orthopedic seems to be the only option now and will probably be too expensive for me to afford so I'll have to figure out finances next depending on the severity of the surgery.

Has anyone's pets had any similar injury or know what possible things could be wrong with that specific joint or ligaments?

Comment: I removed the questions about how to pay for vet treatment, because those would get a better answer if asked seperately. Please open a new question to ask about the financial issues! For more information on why this was done, please see [Why is it better to ask all of my questions seperately and not all at once?](http://meta.pets.stackexchange.com/questions/1837/why-is-it-better-to-ask-all-my-questions-separately-and-not-all-at-once)

Comment: Can you also update with the total time since the injury? He was on anti-inflammatories for 10 days, how much time has he been off them?